# Kibana grok formating of date timestamp

Tags: timestamp, kibana, grok

I am trying to format the datetimestamp in the following log to produce output of:

```
2021-02-04 14:29:42.248281
```

Following is what I have tried so far.

Sample log:

> E0204 14:29:42.248281       1 reflector.go:127]
> pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.19.3/tools/cache/reflector.go:156: Failed
> to watch *v1.Role: failed to list *v1.Role:
> roles.rbac.authorization.k8s.io is forbidden: User
> "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:replicator" cannot list resource
> "roles" in API group "rbac.authorization.k8s.io" at the cluster scope

Custom pattern:

```
K8CUST_DATE %{MONTHNUM}%{MONTHDAY} %{TIME}
```

Grok:

```
%{K8CUST_DATE:log_timestamp}%{GREEDYDATA}
```

Output:

```
{
    "log_timestamp": "0204 14:29:42.248281"
}
```

Could you please tell me what is the next step to produce the output of:

```
{
    "log_timestamp" : 2021-02-04 14:29:42.248281
}
```